# How to remove the number key from the biblatex bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

I'm referencing by `authortitle` so don't need the number key in the bibliography. How do I get rid of it? Here's my code

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=nature,
    citestyle=authortitle
]{biblatex}
```

and here's the output

[image]

How do I get ride of `1.` and `2.`?

Comment: Try `style=authoryear` (because you've told you want to use it) or `style=authortitle` (because you've already used it in the shown code) instead of `style=nature,citestyle=authortitle`. If this does not help, please show a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964) or a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) using `biblatex-examples.bib`.

Comment: @cabohah Apologies, I am citing by `authortitle`. I just corrected my OP. Your suggestion of `style=authortitle` worked perfectly.

Comment: @cabohah Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so the question can be marked as solved?

Comment: @moewe What kind of answer do you expect to a scribbled down question with no MWE and no substance? Would be: "Don't mix cite style `authortitle` with a numeric style like `nature` to be used for the bibliography. Instead simply use `style=authortitle`." enough for an answer? I have been explained, that answers should always contain a full example. But I have little desire to hew a complete example from my fingers, even though the questioner did not feel like giving one, despite explicitly asking.

Comment: @cabohah Sounds OK to me. If the question doesn't have an MWE and can be answered without an MWE, I don't see why one would have to make up one just for the answer. Especially when the answer is clear without an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix `citestyle=authortitle` with a numeric style like `nature` to be used for the bibliography. Instead simply use `style=authortitle` to have the same non-numeric style as style for the bibliography and the cites.